# Google account does not sync and is not cancelable

Tags: sync, google-account

The device in question is a tablet with Android version around 4.2 I guess. I do not have direct access to it.

The Google account shows errors when synchronizing. I want to remove the Google account and add it again.

The problem is that there is no "Remove account" button. I guess it will appear if I cancel the sync in progress. It looks like it hangs and does never terminate. At the bottom of the account avtivity appears the error:

> Sync is currently experiencing problems. It will be back shortly.

But how to cancel it? There is no button for that either and rebooting does not change anything.

I also tried to reset the whole device, but after that I get the exacft same problem.

Comment: Did you check under settings>accounts>Google? There press on the three dots menu and it has an option to remove account

Comment: Yes I checked. That option is missing.

Comment: What's the name of the tablet?

Comment: It is a Tivolino

Comment: Try the Windows approach: "Have you switched it off and on again?" Sometimes helps on Android, too :) Should at least break the sync being in progress.

Comment: I did reboot. It does not help.

Comment: Try removing the account by signing into the same account on a browser and removing the account. Click [here](https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity) and log into the account, scroll down to the name of the device, press on it and select 'remove'

Comment: @Abochur: I can't just "remove" the device from my account. I have the options to lock it and reset it to factory settings. Both are not what I want.